# Modified Data Table

Tags: c#

For example I have this table

```
EmployeeName     EmpoyeeID
John Mark        60001
Bent Ting        60002
Don  Park        60003
```

How I can show the EmployeeID to have a leading asterisk in data table?
Sample: *60001 *60002 *60003

```
  public DataTable ListOfEmployee()
    {
        DataSet ds = null;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
            {

                myDatabaseConnection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * Employee", myDatabaseConnection))
                {
                    ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand);
                   adapter.Fill(ds, "Users");
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

I need to show the dataTable in the crystal report with a leading asterisk in the employee ID

```
public void Employees()
    {
        ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
        Employees ds = new Employees(); // .xsd file name
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Just set the name of data table
        dt.TableName = "Employees";
        dt = ListOfEmployee(); //This function is located below this function
        ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);

        string strReportName = "Employees.rpt";
        string strPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports\\" + strReportName;
        // Your .rpt file path will be below
        rptDoc.Load(strPath);

        //set dataset to the report viewer.
        rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);

        ReportViewer newReportViewer = new ReportViewer();
        newReportViewer.setReport(rptDoc);
        newReportViewer.Show();
    }
```

Comment: There are many ways to do this, each being the "best" way depending on what you are going to be doing with the data after you query it out. Can you explain more (by editing the original question) about what you are doing with the data after you query it out?

Comment: show it where ? It's not very clear what you asking, why can't you just add asterisk ? eg. string astData = "*" + table.GetField<int>("EmpoyeeID").ToString();

Comment: The best solution would be appending the asterisk where you consume the data, not in the datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the **easiest** not the best way to do is to get the data in that format, if and only if it is not meant to be used anywhere else. You can do this in your query

```
Select '*'+id,col1,col2,col3 from employee
```

Though the best way is to modify the column value when you consume it. But obviously that is more headache than adding simply in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Add it into the Crystal report itself.

Something like -

```
"*" & {tblTable.FieldName}
```

(Although I can't remember the syntax for Crystal reports, sorry!)

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but replacing the return statement at the end of your function with the following code should work:

```
DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable clonedTable = table.Clone();
clonedTable.Columns["EmployeeID"].DataType = typeof(String);
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    clonedTable.ImportRow(row);
}
foreach (DataRow row in clonedTable.Rows)
{
    row["EmployeeID"] = "*" + row["EmployeeID"].ToString();
}
return clonedTable;
```

However, as others have said, I would recommend adding the asterick somewhere down the line when the data is read rather than to the table itself.